# grid-template-areas vertically distribute a set of articles

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to get a set of articles to distribute vertically

```
<article class="article">
<h1>Main article area</h1>
<p>In this layout, we display the areas in source order for any screen 
less that 500 pixels wide. We go to a two column layout, and then to a 
three column layout by redefining the grid,and the placement of items on 
the grid.</p>
</article>

<article class="article">
<h1>Main article area</h1>
<p>In this layout, we display the areas in source order for any screen 
less that 500 pixels wide. We go to a two column layout, and then to a 
three column layout by redefining the grid, and the placement of items on 
the grid.</p>
```

But the two article below overlap in browser when CSS looks like so:

```css
grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
grid-template-areas:
  "header  header"
  "nav     nav"
  "sidebar article"
  " .      article"
  "footer      footer";
```

The actual result is that the two article above are on top of each other. I'm just reading up on grids now and gotten myself the CSS bible, as I'm trying to get away from Bootstrap.

The intended result I want is that article 2 is placed below article 1.

---

I was able to get the desired effect by giving the articles unique class names, here is the updated HTML; notice the names 'article' and 'article2', and the articles now distribute vertically:

That being said, it seems to me I am missing something obvious. Surely having same classname 'article' for both article divs (if they as in first post have classname 'article' should work. Or can grid-template-areas not tell the difference if so...

```css
.header {
  grid-area: header;
}
.article {
  grid-area: article;
}
.article2 {
  grid-area: article2;
}
.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
}
.aside {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}
.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "nav"
    "article"
    "article2"
    "sidebar"
    "footer";
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="header">The header</header>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Nav 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nav 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nav 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <article class="article">
            <h1>Main article area</h1>
            <p>In this layout, we display the areas in source order for any screen less that 500 pixels wide. We go to a two column layout, and then to a three column layout by redefining the grid,
                and the placement of items on the grid.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="article2">
            <h1>Main article area</h1>
            <p>In this layout, we display the areas in source order for any screen less that 500 pixels wide. We go to a two column layout, and then to a three column layout by redefining the grid,
                and the placement of items on the grid.</p>
        </article>
        <aside class="aside">Sidebar</aside>
        <footer class="footer">The footer</footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please provide additional HTML and CSS for your header, nav, sidebar, and footer?

Comment: @Paulie_D That starts to make sense now. I think I'll create a container div and keep articles within instead of adding each article to the template area which seems now a bit nutty. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A grid-area has no idea how to layout information with itself. If you apply the same grid area to multiple elements they will sit on top of one another like layers. You would need to wrap the articles in a div and place that in your grid-area,,,then the normal layout algorithm would apply.

> The grid-area CSS property is a shorthand property for grid-row-start, grid-column-start, grid-row-end and grid-column-end, specifying a grid item’s size and location within the grid by contributing a line, a span, or nothing (automatic) to its grid placement, thereby specifying the edges of its grid area.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: orange;
}

main {
  grid-area: article;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background: pink;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none
}

.aside {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background: lightblue;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "nav nav" "sidebar article" ".       article" "footer footer";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">The header</header>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Nav 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nav 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nav 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <article class="article">
        <h1>Main article area</h1>
        <p>In this layout, we display the areas in source order for any screen less that 500 pixels wide. We go to a two column layout, and then to a three column layout by redefining the grid, and the placement of items on the grid.</p>
      </article>

      <article class="article2">
        <h1>Main article area</h1>
        <p>In this layout, we display the areas in source order for any screen less that 500 pixels wide. We go to a two column layout, and then to a three column layout by redefining the grid, and the placement of items on the grid.</p>
      </article>
    </main>
    <aside class="aside">Sidebar</aside>
    <footer class="footer">The footer</footer>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I thank you. Need to delve into the finer grid parts of the CSS bible I now have on my desk.